# If Robocopy is run from a different server, does it copy the files across the network if the source and destination are the same server?

Tags: deployment, files, robocopy, build-server

As part of our build and deployment process, we deploy applications from Server A (our build server running GitHub self-hosted runner) to Server B (web server).  The process involves publishing from Server A to a temporary folder on Server B.  When publish is complete I run a Robocopy script from Server A where the source and destination folders are both on Server B.

My question is: Does running Robocopy from Server A, cause the files to be passed from Server B's temporary folder back thru Server A then on to Server B's production folder?

If so, is there a better way to do this?  These folders are right next to each other and the process should be super quick.

Comment: How do run the robocopy command? I imagine `robocopy.exe  \\ServerB\src \\ServerB\dst` might behave quite differently compared to for example `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerB -Scriptblock { robocopy.exe c:\src d:\dst}`

Comment: Why not run robocopy from Server B?

Comment: @joeqwerty Server A is my build server where the GitHub Action runs.  How do you recommend running the robocopy from Server B?

Answer (score 4):

Modern SMB 2+ client/server implementations supports [server side copies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb2/cd0162e4-7650-4293-8a2a-d696923203ef) and [robocopy supports this feature](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Server-Side_Copy#Client_Support).

I just tried copying a big file from ServerA/folder to ServerA/folder2 (a Win2016 server) from ClientA (a Win10 client) and I confirm that data does *not* flow via the client running `robocopy`; rather, the copy is local to the server.

Comment: Might be worth noting that this only works with a single server (not across two remote servers like some might believe), and directory walking with `/s` or `/e` still happens from the client.

Comment: @shodanshok thanks for testing that.  That's good to know!  Can I ask how you tested it?  Did you use a tool to monitor the traffic?  Both of my servers are running Windows Server 2022 so that's a good sign.

Comment: @Airn5475 I copied a big file while watching `eth` bandwidth via `task manager`, comparing it with the (much faster) reported copy speed.